# Ubuntu software-center not installed

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 version. Ubuntu software-center not displayed on my left panel. I searched for it, but nothing displayed. Can any one help me to solve this problem. Is there any other way to install software-center in my machine?

Thanks & Regards,
Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

In the terminal.

Start the terminal with with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

press `ctrl` then `alt` then `t`
then type`sudo apt-get install software-center`
then input your password
and it will install but DO NOT close close the window until its done

Answer (score -1):

From terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

To access terminal, simply search for it or press `CTRL + ALT + T`.